# Firebase wrong active user calculated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am starting with Android Firebase, and I have some doubts about the dashboard and other components. In my app (not published yet with the firebase feature) I did the full set up and i was testing with two mobiles. The strange behaviour I have detected is that the firebase dashboard says that I have 25 active users, when as maximum there are two devices, so, is this normal?

My other doubt is about the events, I do not know if I've setup well following the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start) or maybe I should use another way with firebase. My aim is to send events like when the user press a concrete button, or to know how many rounds the user play in a game which is inside the app, so is this the way?

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I see many parameters to my aim, so I just only need to send a name of the event, just simple.

Thanks in advance!!